# Measure of the Cantor space $2^{\omega_1}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, haar-measure

What kind of measure is there on the Borel algebra (or Baire algebra) of the Cantor space $2^{\omega_1}$?

Is it the Haar measure? If so, why is the Lebesgue measure not good enough?

Answer (score -1):

**A summary of a few basic properties:**

1. No measure is related to the Haar measure because it is not a group.
2. The usual topology is the Tychonoff topology and so you induce a measure by taking any measure on disjoint sets generating the $\sigma$-algebra (some people call them cylinders).
3. Depending on the construction one of those measures will be the Hausdorff measure of the right Hausdorff dimension.
4. The Lebesgue measure is zero and so it is not very useful.

Comment: Isn't it true that $2^{\omega_1}$ is a compact topological group?

Comment: $2^{\omega_1}$ has a natural compact group structure, though - consider bitwise XOR (or symmetric difference if you prefer).

Comment: So there must exists a Haar measure on the Borel sets of $2^{\omega_1}$.

Comment: As I wrote, the "usual topology is the Tychonoff topology". I wonder whether we want to complicate the question unnecessarily. The OP wrote "the Borel algebra", so I wonder why the peculiar insistence on something unrelated. Yes, everybody knows what xor is.